# Python Numba non deterministic results

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, parallel-processing, numba

I'm trying to use `numba.njit` to speed up some mathematical functions.

The function takes in an array of numbers as input and for each element `i` it checks how many neighbors (in some defined proximity `n`) are smaller than `i`. This is known as a  *local rank transform* and this function is 100% deterministic.

So I wrote this and it behaves as expected:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np


@nb.njit(["float64[:](float64[:], int32)",
          "float32[:](float32[:], int32)",
          "uint8[:](uint8[:], int32)"], parallel=True, nogil=True)
def local_rank_transform_jit(sig, n):
    pad = n//2
    result = np.zeros_like(sig)
    padded_sig = np.zeros(len(sig) + n - 1)
    padded_sig[pad:-pad] = sig
    
    for idx in nb.prange(pad, len(result) + pad):
        neighb = padded_sig[idx - pad:idx + pad]
        result[idx - pad] = np.sum(neighb < padded_sig[idx])
    
    return result
```

Then I realized I'll be running this over many inputs and I can parallelize it, so I wrote the following function:

```
@nb.njit(["float64[:,:](float64[:,:], int32)",
          "float32[:,:](float32[:,:], int32)",
          "uint8[:,:](uint8[:,:], int32)"], parallel=True, nogil=True)
def local_rank_transform_many_jit(signals, n):
    pad = n//2
    result = np.zeros_like(signals[0])
    all_results = np.zeros_like(signals)
    padded_sig = np.zeros(len(result) + n - 1)
    
    for i in nb.prange(len(signals)):
            padded_sig[pad:-pad] = signals[i]

            for j in nb.prange(pad, len(result) + pad):
                neighb = padded_sig[j - pad:j + pad + 1]
                result[j - pad] = np.sum(neighb < padded_sig[j])
            
            all_results[i] = result
            
    return all_results
```

But when using this one, I'm getting strange results.

First of all, the results are non-deterministic, i.e. I run the function twice with the same input and get different outputs.

And then, I also noticed I was getting **wrong** results, for example:

```
> signals
array([[2603., 1352., 2087.,  240.,  979.],
       [1633., 1181., 1328., 1956., 2808.],
       [1628., 2233., 1781.,  448.,  737.],
       [ 574., 2332., 1245.,  246., 2697.],
       [2170.,  312.,  942.,  811., 1497.]])


> local_rank_transform_many_jit(signals, 3)
array([[3., 0., 1., 1., 2.],
       [3., 0., 1., 1., 2.],
       [3., 0., 1., 1., 2.],
       [1., 2., 1., 0., 2.],
       [3., 0., 1., 1., 2.]])
```

In this case, `3` is an impossible output since an element cannot be greater than 3 elements in a neighborhood of 3. That would imply it is greater than itself!

I suspect the parallelization created some kind of a race condition, but I don't know what did I do wrong.

Comment: This may be due to the two `nb.prange` : try with only one `nb.prange`, especially the encompassing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`padded_sig[pad:-pad]` gets overwritten by different values `signals[i]` in parallel, therefore the outcome of

```
neighb = padded_sig[j - pad:j + pad + 1]
```

and

```
result[j - pad] = np.sum(neighb < padded_sig[j])
```

is not deterministic.

You need a separate array `padded_sig` for each `i`, or make sure that for each `i` a unique slice of `padded_sig` gets written to.

Answer (score 0):

The working code after implementing the accepted answer by [mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1):

```
@nb.njit(["float64[:,:](float64[:,:], int32)",
          "float32[:,:](float32[:,:], int32)",
          "uint8[:,:](uint8[:,:], int32)"], parallel=True, nogil=True)
def local_rank_transform_many_jit(signals, n):
    pad = n//2
    num_sig, sig_len = signals.shape
    all_results = np.zeros_like(signals)
    padded_signals = np.zeros((num_sig, sig_len + n - 1))
    padded_signals[:, pad:-pad] = signals
    
    for i in nb.prange(num_sig):
        for j in nb.prange(pad, sig_len + pad):
            neighb = padded_signals[i, j - pad:j + pad + 1]
            all_results[i, j - pad] = np.sum(neighb < padded_signals[i, j])

    return all_results
```